# Is there any way to retrieve the serial number (SSN) of an android device via a USB connection?

Tags: android, adt, nexus-7, serial-number

I have a Google Nexus 7 (2013) that's under warranty with a dead LCD screen. To get it replaced I need to provide Asus with the serial number (SSN) which is available in 3 places:
- In the device's settings (accessed using LCD, which is dead)
- On the Box (No room for those in a studio apartment)
- Inside the back panel (but removing the panel will void the warranty)

I have my Nexus 7 connected to my PC and can communicate with it using ADT (Android Development Toolkit). Is there any way I can get the serial number using ADT or other software? I need the actual serial number (SSN) for the device and no the ADT device instance serial number.

Comment: Anything in `adb shell getprop` seem to be of the right format?  And are you sure the adb device identifier is wrong?  On the two nexus phones I tried that seems to match ro.serialno and the display in the settings menu, though neither was made by Asus.

Comment: You could also try to get into the settings menu (with your finger or adb event injection) and monitor your progress using ADB screenshots (via DDMS or one of the host-side screencasting applets).

Comment: Both of those are great suggestions, I'll explore them both and post my findings. Thanks Chris!

Answer (score 11):

No grep command is needed, just use getprop :

```
adb shell getprop ro.serialno
```

Answer (score 7):

Found it! The serial number can be retreived using:

`adb shell getprop | grep ro.boot.serialno`

I used DDMS to double verify and it is in fact the correct serial number.
Thanks Chris!

Comment: this returns UDID, not SerialNumber

Answer (score 4):

Adb given one command for get serial number

```
adb get-serialno
```

But it not works always

Comment: it doesn't always return the serial number though.

Comment: To my android devices it works. Perhaps on some other devices it doesn't works

Comment: for me this returns IP address of the device

Comment: `get-serialno` returns IP?? you sure?

Comment: It returns the IP if you connect to the device over TCP rather than over USB.

Answer (score 2):

For Samsung note 3 I do this **>>** **adb shell getprop ril.serialnumber**

it print the Serial Number not UDID number as has been answered above!

Answer (score 0):

Another method is to use this command:

```
adb shell idme print | grep  "^serial"
```